# Why everything wants to come into its lowest state of potential energy and why there manybe more than one position of stability?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, equilibrium

Suppose we have a solid hemisphere , one can observe that from both curve and flat surface is kept on ground it acquires a stable position on its own , why its does so ? And if its true then why not the flat or the curve one rotates/moves to transform into other by seeing which among $\frac{4 R}{3 \pi}$ and $R - \frac{4 R}{3 \pi}$ is minimum using the fact of minimum PE(Potential energy(. So only one stable position ? R is the radius of hemisphere and 4R/3pi is the centre of mass location of the hemisphere from flat surface from centre . By move/rotate i mean to be able to go to the lowest energy configuration out of Mg(4R/3pi) or Mg(3pi-4)R/3pi by itself

Comment: Hello ProblemDestroyer and welcome to Physics SE. Your answer seems to be a bit confusing and vague. I believe you should add some more information and possibly make some clarifications. For example, what is "keot", what flat/curved should rotate/move, what exactly do you mean by "move", what do you consider to be a "move", what are the 4R/3pi and R - 4R/3pi you mention, what is R anyway and what does PE mean (possibly probability of error, percentage error, potential energy). This way, it will be easier for people around here to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Sure @ZaellixA .

Comment: Well, it does seem better but again, I suggest you use MathJax to format your formulas (I edited the first formulas but I am not sure what Mg() is to edit the newly added ones too). Additionally, what does Mg() mean? I assume is magnitude() of the quantity in the parentheses but it could very well be mass times acceleration of gravity. Please try to be as descriptive as possibly to help people help you.

Comment: Sure @ZaellixA .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common to have a situation where the potential energy as a function of some parameter has more than one minimum. In this case there are various local minima and there is usually just one global minimum (the lowest of all the local minima), but it can happen that there are several minima which have the same energy and are lower than all the others.

First all of, we have energy conservation so a system of given energy cannot move just anywhere on its potential energy surface unless it is able to exchange energy with other systems. In the example of the hemisphere, in order to role from the state with the curved surface down to the state with the flat surface down, the system first needs to go to the half-way rolled-over state where it has higher potential energy. It will only be able to do that if another system pushes it or if it had enough kinetic energy in the first place. If it did have enough kinetic energy (e.g. in a rotational motion) then it could indeed flip over. It would flip over and what happens next depends on the interaction with the ground. A real hemisphere would then impact on the ground in such a way as to deliver some energy to the ground in the form of sound and heat, so the hemisphere loses energy and will eventually settle with the flat side down in this case.

More generally, the fact that systems tend to move towards minimum potential energy is related not just to energy but also to entropy. If a system is to settle at a place of lower total energy then, as I already said, it must be in interaction with other systems. Such an interaction will move energy between the systems, and in principle the energy could go either way, and oscillate between the systems. But in practice there is always some mechanism whereby entropy can increase, and as a result the joint system changes state irreversibly towards the higher entropy configuration. In the example of the hemisphere this could be an overall state where there is more entropy in the floor, for example. Or it could be that the floor is unchanged but the sphere itself absorbs some heat and thus has higher entropy and less rotational kinetic energy. In other examples it could be owing to giving off thermal radiation or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful explanation